# How can you create in Netbeans a new PHP project with source files located in local network?

Tags: php, networking, netbeans, ftp

I'm trying to create a new **PHP project** in a situation where our client gave us only **remote desktop connection** to to their files.

**How does it work usually in Netbeans:**

To put it simple when a project is created with external sources we can click in our project on the single file and upload and download it (via ftp).

[image: nb options to upload and download via ftp]

I'd like to be able to do this also on remote files located in a server which can be reached by our local network but which hasn't ftp installed.

**Extra details**

Until now we have been able to work normally with this setup by using Dreamweaver which allows to set in the server options an address located in the local network.

I really would like to switch to Netbeans and **being able to click on upload and download on the local files to sync with their server** but I can't find a way to achieve this.

There seem to be no option when creating a new project that allows this kind of setup. Selecting remote website seem to allow only ftp synch.

[image: List of projects types]

On the other hand if i select "Local web site" i can select the files in the local network, but NB doesn't allow me to make a local copy of them.

**note 1**: the server we're accessing hasn't ftp installed.

**note 2**: the "copy files from sources folder to another location" isn't really an option for me since I'd like to keep separated my local copy from what's on the server (and this setup I think would just copy the files without giving me any control on them).

**note 3**: creating a project with existing sources seem to allow only to have remote files reachable via ftp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be useful to have some versioning system (git, mercurial, svn...). Can you mount the network drive in Windows? (see [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-shortcut-map-network-drive#1TC=windows-7) ). This would at least allow you to easily create project from existing sources (although working via network could be quite slow)

One hacky way I can think of is to:

- mount the network drive as described above and map it to some letter, say Z
- install local FTP server (e.g. FileZilla)
- configure FileZilla FTP server to use the network drive as "ftp home" (aka the folder which FileZilla will use for saving files sent over FTP) - simply use Z:\ path to point to the mounted network drive mapped to letter Z
- in NetBeans, create a new PHP project from remote server (where remote server is actually your local FileZilla server)

In theory, this should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried this way and now I'm doing it again. The problem is that everytime i try to set up a local ftp connection to a mounted drive it only shows an empty folder when i connect to it (i have the local network folder mapped as W:. I can't find a way to show its contents via ftp. Instead if i access C: i can see the contents normally..) Do you have any idea about what could be the problem?

Comment: ok nevermind i found this: https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=5154 ;)

Comment: seems that there is no way to access the local network source via ftp, not even with filezilla. Everytime i try to connect to it a get an empty folder.

Comment: Still can't make it work, but I guess this is as close as I can get. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fragment from [NetBeans site](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#existing-web-sources):

> To set up a NetBeans project for an existing web application:

```
Choose File > New Project (Ctrl-Shift-N on Windows/Cmd-Shift-N on OS X).
Choose Java Web > Web Application with Existing Sources. Click Next.
In the Name and Location page of the wizard, follow these steps:
    In the Location field, enter the folder that contains the web application's source root folders and web page folders.
    Type a project name.
    (Optional) Change the location of the project folder.
(Optional) Select the Use Dedicated Folder for Storing Libraries checkbox and specify the location for the libraries folder. See Sharing Project Libraries in NetBeans IDE for more information on this option.
(Optional) Select the Set as Main Project checkbox. When you select this option, keyboard shortcuts for commands such as Clean and Build Main Project (Shift-F11) apply to this project.
Click Next to advance to the Server and Settings page of the wizard.
(Optional) Add the project to an existing enterprise application.
Select a server to which to deploy. If the server that you want does not appear, click Add to register the server in the IDE.
Set the source level to the Java version on which you want the application to run.
(Optional) Adjust the context path. By default, the context path is based on the project name.
Click Next to advance to the Existing Sources and Libraries page of the wizard.
Verify all of the fields on the page, such as the values for the Web Pages Folder and Source Package Folders.
Click Finish.
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm trying to setup a php project. Also there there is the option to work on existing sources, but I'd like to work on a local copy and then sync it by clicking on upload/download on single files (instead of working directly on the "production" directory).